# Openssl c++ Disable debug strings

Tags: c++, gcc, openssl

Those debug strings may expose what function doing, how can i remove it / disable?

I used vcpkg to install openssl for tripplet: openssl:x64-mingw-static 3.1.1#1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are required [by the license](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) to mention that you use OpenSSL. Also know that reverse engineers typically check large constant tables against known constant tables for cryptography algorithms.

Regardless, if you think it can help you in any way, you can recompile OpenSSL and modify the `ERR_raise_data` macro in `err.h` to pass dummy values to `ERR_set_debug`:

```
# define ERR_raise_data                                         \
    (ERR_new(),                                                 \
     ERR_set_debug("x",123,"x"),     \
     ERR_set_error)
```